# Is there a way for a class template to deduce the size of a parameter pack passed to the constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

If I have a class template like such:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct foo
{
    template<std::same_as<T>... Ts>
    foo(Ts... ts);
}
```

Is there any way whatsoever to deduce the template parameter `N` from the size of the parameter pack passed to the `foo` constructor? So that `foo` can be instantiated like so:

```
auto f = foo(10,10,10); // foo<int, 3>
```

Or is it simply impossible? Is there no getting around having to type `foo<int, 3>(10,10,10)`?

Comment: Look up *class template deduction guides*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a deduction guide for this is straight-forward:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
requires (std::same_as<T, Ts> && ...) // optional
foo(T, Ts...) -> foo<T, sizeof...(Ts)+1>;
```

or

```
template<typename T, std::same_as<T>... Ts>
foo(T, Ts...) -> foo<T, sizeof...(Ts)+1>;
```